# REST Response adds \ - Media Type application/json vs text/plain

Tags: json, content-type, http-accept-header

I have an endpoint that returns the following response,

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7135/api/v1/Initiate' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

returns

```
"{\"ID\":\"987139672\"}"
```

Notice the \ after key and value.

Vs.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7135/api/v1/Initiate' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

returns

```
{"ID":"987139673"}
```

Why is it happening?